# how to use property Bool shouldautoplay MPMovieplayercontroller ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play video automatically without on click of play button.
So i found a property of `MPMovieplayerController` "BOOl Shouldautoplay"
But don't know how to use it.

Comment: You should start by reading the documentation of [`MPMoviePlayerController `](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: The link is there, just click on [`MPMoviePlayerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileName]];

    moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
    moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame ;

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view] ;

    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: what if i am using 3rd Party Media Player ??

Comment: If you are using a third party media player then you should look in their documentation. Since there API can completely differ from [`MPMoviePlayerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: u have to use after prepare to play like this 
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;

Answer (score 0):

this is another way

```
-(void) mpVideo:(NSString *)fileName {

    videoFileName=fileName;
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileName]];

    moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 0;
    moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame ;
    [orientationHandler VideoStart];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view] ;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
}

-(void)moviePlaybackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {

    // your custom code which you want to play after the player did finish playing
}
```